# Symbols in chicken scheme egss don't get bound

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

Using chicken scheme, i installed some 'eggs', but when trying to use any procedure from them, the procedures name is never bound to an actual procedure. For example, on the csi interpreter:

```
#;1> (import glfw3)
#;2> (init)
Error: unbound variable: glfw3#init
```

The same thing happens with any procedure or value from any other 'egg' that I've tested, both in the interpreter and the compiler; nothing from any 'egg' ever gets bound.

Comment: Can you please add details about your code? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to be using CHICKEN 4?  If so, you probably need `(use glfw3)` instead of `(import glfw3)`.  If you are using CHICKEN 5, `(import glfw3)` is correct and `init` should work.

Comment: That's it thank you. For some reason I got an outdated version.

Comment: Many distros still have a woefully outdated version of CHICKEN. In such cases, it can be a better idea to compile and install it manually (it's quite easy).